# Some basic questions on Android downloading

Tags: android

While downloading the things related to Android 3.0 (API 11) I downloaded all the things except

1. Google API's
2. XOOM
3. Google USB driver

i.e. through the Android SDK manager I downloaded only the below things

1. Android SDK tools
2. SDK Platform
3. Samples for SDK

Actually I wanted to download all the things under Android 3.0 but was unable to do so because of Internet and huge size of files. 
 **So I want to ask what is the actual use of things which I haven't downloaded and therefore what type of application I cannot develop due to the absence of these things ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Google APIs contains mainly Google Maps library. [Description of Google APIs add-on.](https://developers.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/)
2. XOOM is Motorola Xoom image for emulator.
3. [Google USB Driver](http://developer.android.com/sdk/oem-usb.html) is needed to connect Android device to your PC (only for Windows).

Comment: --(1)XOOM is an emulator, since i already have the default emulator which came with the installation so i don't need the XOOM ?---------------------------(2)Google USB driver i might not need since i don't have an android device------------------(3) The only thing is Google API ? -- ------------So can you tell me what type of application i can't make due to Google API. I know you told google Maps what i want to know their impact on application ? I am newbie

Comment: 1. Yes, you don't need Xoom emulator. 2. If you don't have device then you don't need the driver. 3. You need Google Maps if you want to do app displaying maps from Google. Example of application with Google Maps: http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html or https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.maps.mytracks

Answer (score 1):

Actually you won't be able to use services from google like maps.

> Google APIs Add-On is an extension to the Android SDK development environment that lets you develop applications for devices that include Google's set of custom applications, libraries, and services. A central feature of the add-on is the Maps external library, which lets you add powerful mapping capabilities to your Android application.

source: https://developers.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/

My suggestion is to use eclipse IDE + Android api's & sdk, not separated.

In the case where you follow a tutorial and you're missing a library to implement a feature, eclipse will notify you about that missing library/add-on and ask you if you want it to be installed.

Answer (score 1):

- You can't use the Google-Api - more details on what the Google API add-on contains, can be found here: https://developers.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/index
- Xoom is a Tablet, I suspect an emulator or maybe some Xoom-specific Api, hence unless you want a Xoom-specific emulator, no need to install this one
- You'll have to make sure yourself to get a real-device running/connected via USB (using the manufacturer's USB drivers for instance)

You don't really need to first three things to develop. But I'd say depending on what you're going to do, installating the Google Api might be a good idea, since it for instance offers interaction with Google Maps.

About the USB drivers: They're not needed per se, but might come in handy, if you want to deploy/debug to a real device which will be attached via USB. Devices included in that USB driver package can be found here:

http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html

Comment: You mean to say these 3 things i.e. Google API, Xoom and USB might not need in any application

Comment: @R122 I I made my answer a bit more specific to answer your questions.